# Using `*ngFor` on child component is laggier than when wrapped in `<div>` in Chrome devtools

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ngfor

I have the following page:

**list.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-list",
  template: `
    <app-item *ngFor="let data of listData" [data]="data"></app-item>
  `
})
export class ListComponent {
  listData = [...Array(1000)].map((_, idx) => idx);
}
```

**item.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-item",
  template: `<div>{{data}}</div>`,
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @Input() data: number
}
```

Then I do this:

1. Open Chrome Dev tools
2. Click *'Select an element in the page to inspect it'*
3. Select item component

The page lags considerably.

However if I change code to:

**list.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-list",
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let data of listData">
      <app-item [data]="data"></app-item>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ListComponent {
  listData = [...Array(1000)].map((_, idx) => idx);
}
```

The lag seems to be diminished.

Could someone explain this behavior.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-roman-6khhs?file=/src/app/list.component.ts

Chrome version：v93.0.961.38

Comment: This is a rather interesting question. FWIW, Firefox's debugger seems to be relatively faster than Chrome's on both cases. Would appreciate a canonical answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a guess based on my own observations and not backed by actual knowledge of the chrome / chromium code, but I assume it's got to do with how the chrome debugger highlights the queried element (in this case element under the cursor).

Note that debugger does not apply any additional class / styles to highlighted element - this is because debugger affecting the actual DOM tree would pretty much be a bad idea.

Instead, it seems to persist the "additional" styling outside of the DOM and let know the rendering engine that something changed.

But this change happens in a slightly different way, since normally it would cause reflow / repaint of the whole DOM tree up to the root. Instead, they seem to simply limit the repaint to the first non-inline parent to improve performance. This makes sense, since they know exactly what their changes will affect.

So, in your first case, it have to repaint the whole div in your app-component (which is a first block container) - so it repaints all 1000 elements.

In your second case, the first non-inline parent is the div wrapping a single element, so the repaint is much faster.

You can apply the `:host {display: block;}` style to your `app-item` and observe the same improved performance.